# How do I pass 2 variables to Wordpress add_rewrite_rule

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I am currently setting up a rewrite rule in WP so that `/hit-list/place/sydney` shows itself to php like `/hit-list/?tax=place&childtax=sydney`

I've used this rewrite rule but it's not working. Can someone please let me know what I may be doing wrong here?

```
function hitListRules(){
  add_rewrite_rule(
    'hit-list/(.+?)/(.+?)/?$',
    'hit-list?tax=$matches[1]&childtax=$matches[2]',
    'top'
  );
}
add_action('init', 'hitListRules');
```

Comment: Is this in a function?  Are you hooking to `init` ?

Comment: @HowardE yes inside a function, I've made an edit

Answer (score 0):

After much deliberation I managed to figure it out myself;

```
//for registering the query variables
function hitList_register_query_vars($vars){
  $vars[] = 'parent_tax';
  $vars[] = 'child_tax';
  return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'hitList_register_query_vars');

function hitList_pagination_rewrite(){
  //adding rewrite rule for 2 vars
  add_rewrite_rule(
    'hit-list/(.+?)/(.+?)/?$',
    'index.php?pagename=hit-list&parent_tax=$matches[1]&child_tax=$matches[2]',
    'top'
  );

  //adding rewrite rule for 1 var
  add_rewrite_rule(
    'hit-list/(.+?)/?$',
    'index.php?pagename=hit-list&parent_tax=$matches[1]',
    'top'
  );
}
add_action('init', 'hitList_pagination_rewrite');
```

And don't forget to flush rewrite cache after this.